# Passing struct of array as reference c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, structure

I am new to structure programming, and I find it quite confusing when trying to pass a structure of array in c++. I have a project to do for college, a Star Trek game. This is the sample code:

```
void main_menu(char,char [][sz2],int&,struct enterpriseSt*,struct klingonSt*[100]);
void combat_menu(char [][sz2],struct enterpriseSt*,int&,struct klingonSt*[100]);
struct enterpriseSt
{
    int energy_level;
    int damage;
    int torpedo_count;
};
struct klingonSt
{
    int energy_level;
    int damage;
    int position[2];
};
int main()
{
    struct enterpriseSt enterprise;
    enterprise.energy_level=energy_ent_max;
    enterprise.damage=0;
    enterprise.torpedo_count=10;

    struct klingonSt klingon[100];

    main_menu(command,galaxy,turn,&enterprise,&klingon);
    return 0;
}
void main_menu(char command, char galaxy[][sz2],int& turn,struct enterpriseSt * enterprise,struct klingonSt * klingon[100])
{
 combat_menu(galaxy,enterprise,turn,klingon);
}
```

I have two structures, enterpriseSt and klingonSt. I can pass enterprise no problem, but with klingon I am struggling. I get all kinds of errors, doesn't matter what combination I use. The current one is:

```
error: cannot convert ‘klingonSt (*)[100]’ to ‘klingonSt**’ for argument ‘5’ to ‘void main_menu(char, char (*)[64], int&, enterpriseSt*, klingonSt**)’
```

I've made such a mess with it now. Could someone please explain it to me why it works with enterprise but not with klingon? 
I use g++ compiler on Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is that you think that arrays are pointers [which they aren't](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html).

Comment: You say that combat_menu isn't showing errors, and main_menu does, but you are using them differently.

Comment: Right now I don't know what I think any more.. Thanks for your comments guys, but could someone actually explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in misunderstanding the arguments parsing rules.

you think that `struct klingonSt*[100]` is *a pointer to the array of size 100 of type struct klingonSt*, but actually when argument parsing, array and function symbols that should be situated on the right of token has higher priority, than symbols on the left of expression.

So, lets first write the expression with argument name included:

```
struct klingonSt*var[100]
```

and parse it

1. var
2. is an array of size 100 (as array symbol on the right has higher priority, than pointer on the left)
3. of pointers
4. to the type struct klingonSt

so, `struct klingonSt*var[100]` is actually is *array of size 100 of pointers to struct klingonSt*.

to pass *a pointer to the array of size 100 of type struct klingonSt* you should change parsing precedence using parenthesis:

```
struct klingonSt(*var)[100]
```

or

```
struct klingonSt(*)[100]
```

If you change your definition, your code will compile fine.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! After making changes you suggested the code compiled fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a bit confused on passing arrays to functions.  When this is done, the array decays into a pointer to the first element of the array.  You can declare the parameter as an array, but the array range is ignored by the compiler, and not enforced at runtime.  Thus, for this style of coding, you'd just want to pass the array as a pointer, and length as a separate parameter (I've omitted your other params for clarity):

```
void main_menu(enterpriseSt*, int enterpriseCount, klingonSt*, int klingonCount);
```

Some alternatives to consider:

Adopting a modern C++ style, and use std containers like vector/list, passing them by reference.

```
void main_menu(vector<enterpriseSt> & enterprises, vector<klingonSt> & klingons);
```

Or, using a template wrapper to pass sized local arrays implicitly:

```
template<size_t eCount, size_t kCount>
void main_menu(enterpriseSt (&enterprises)[eCount], klingonSt (&klingons)[kCount])
{
  main_menu(enterprises, eCount, klingons, kCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that

```
struct klingonSt * klingon[100]
```

is an array of 100 `struct klingonSt *` rather than a point to 100 `struct klingonSt`

use `struct klingonSt  klingon[][100]` instead.